# Modify/truncate path in path based routing with Azure application gateway

Tags: azure, reverse-proxy, azure-application-gateway

let's say the Application gateway receives a request http://contoso.com/images and is configured to forward that to backendserver.contoso.com. Using a path based routing rule (`/images/*` for example).

I want the application gateway not to retain the `/images` path in the request URL. I need this to be truncated, in which case the request will simply be http://contoso.com/. Any path after the `/images` will remain intact though.

Is it possible? Any help/clue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have aslo asked the same question on MSDN (see last comment) here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-url-route-arm-ps.  Please give me a hint if anybody encountered any workaround to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could do this today with PowerShell/CLI. In the backend http setting associated with the pool, please specify a -Path parameter. For example -

```
Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings -Path "/" -Name setting1 -Port 80 -Protocol Http -CookieBasedAffinity Disabled
```

When `-Path` is not specified at all, incoming request is routed to backend as is - which is the default behavior. When specified as `"/"` it removes the matching path from URI. If specified as a non-null value, then the specified value is used in place of matched path.

Answer (score 0):

Amsrivas and Stephens answer is correct, but the poweshell CLI seems to have changed, at least @ version 5.5.0 and now you have to perfrom this opperation using the following commands:

```
# Get gateway object    
$AppGw = Get-AzureRmApplicationGateway -Name "YOUR GATEWAY NAME" -ResourceGroupName "YOUR GATEWAY RESOURCE GROUP"
# Show current settings
Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings -ApplicationGateway $AppGw
# Set path on local object (other values are whatever you want)
Set-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings -ApplicationGateway $AppGw -Name "YOUR SETTING NAME" -Port "80" -Protocol "Http" -CookieBasedAffinity "Disabled" -RequestTimeout 30 -Path "/"
# Commit changes back to Azure
$UpdatedAppGw = Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $AppGw
# Show new settings as applied in Azure
Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings -ApplicationGateway $UpdatedAppGw
```